# Scaling a view with setScaleY does not move other views below

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, scale

I'm trying to implement a pull-to-zoom header in a scrollview. I managed to zoom the header using setScaleX and setScaleY while scrolling up and down, but the problem is my header overlaps the view below it.

Is there any way to scale a view and move everything that comes after it?

I tried translating the views but I cannot find the right amount to translate, so there's always overlapping or blank space

I'm using vertical LinearLayout and also tried with RelativeLayout with the header at the top, followed by a LinearLayout with layout_below

Answer (score 0):

I switched to ValueAnimator and added and updateListener. Inside I called requestLayout to my view and that fixed the issue. Now when the view is scaled, below views are pushed downd

Comment: It's great that you found a good solution, but this question and answer would be more valuable to future readers if you post the generic code of the scope of the question/answer to both the question and answer, but obviously that is at your own discretion.